# PC randomly dies

Tags: windows-xp, crash

EDIT:

After everything that was done, when we took it back onsite the system crashed within two hours (after being on for a few days straight in the shop)

The big guys upstairs decided to go ahead and get another pc.

EndEdit:

I have a baffling problem and wanted to know if you guys could give me a little advice.

We have two computers with roughly the same hardware from completely different companies (one is actually in house here at the shop) that are having the same issues.

These computers will randomly go black, the screens shut off but the fans in the PC are still spinning, the only way to get these computers to come back up is to do a cold boot, either by holding in the power button or removing power from the machine.

Focusing on one computer, we replaced the Motherboard, ram, PSU and put the computer on a UPS which shows no faults on the line and gives stable power.

Also, the clients computer has "never" crashed or done this while it is in the shop. These computers can go for a couple of weeks at a time without any issues, then crash 3 times in one day, then go back to working fine for another few days.

I have run a 24 hour stress test using "Heavy Load", I ran several tests with S&M, full and specific tests, long and short, all with safe mode disabled.

I ran the Video Memory Stress test 3 full passes, I let MemTest run to 600%

I have yet to find any errors or instability in this system while it is in the shop.

However, as one note, some of the work done on this pc was done before i arrived in this company and the person before me did not always date things, so im not 100% sure when the initial call for the computer shutting down happened, but the time between the motherboard being replaced and the next call was about a month.

We've spent a decent amount of time trying to figure these two computers out, with nothing to show for it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Other info in response to questions:
UPS is at client location, that was put in early on and the problem has not stopped
Other PC's on the same circuit run fine
This happens randomly, right in the middle of use or in the middle of the night, likely not a standby mode issue
The current pc has the original case, disk drive, processor.

By the way, a few weeks ago we also updated the bios.

We have been running core temp on it, both on location and in shop and the cored never get above about 60c

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the screen and the computer is virus free? Have you also used a different hard drive in it? Just in case something could be wrong with the software on the hard-drive?

Comment: "focusing on one computer" so this computer still has which original parts then?  Optical drive, hard drive... any expansion cards or USB devices that are still being connected to it?  Have you considered providing the client with a "loaner" computer for a month, to see if a COMPLETELY different computer starts experiencing these issues in the same location?  You put that computer on a UPS... and you did that in the client's location?

Comment: Check the standby mode too, my last PC crashed every time it would try to enter standby.

Comment: added responses to answer

Comment: I would reinstall a fresh installation of Windows.  This would confirm if its a hardware problem or a driver ( i.e. software ) problem.

Comment: We did a couple of things to it to try and alleviate the problem, If the problem still persists I think saving the parts database and installing a fresh copy of windows on a new harddrive is the next logical step

Answer (score 2):

If you swapped out that many parts and ran stress tests without fail, I'm thinking it is software or hard drive related. Put a new hard drive in with fresh install of Windows or even Ubuntu Linux. Also check the system logs.